# Passing a variable out of a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

Is it possible to pass a variable out of a SQL query?
I am building up the initial query using a variable. I have added a simplified subset of my query below.
Thanks

```
declare @query Nvarchar(max)
declare @ColumnName Nvarchar(max)
set @ColumnName = 'MyColumn'
SET @query = 'Select ' +  @ColumnName + ' from [MyTable] WHERE [MyCondition]'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

Can I return this result as a variable to pass to another query?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL server 2017

Comment: Add the <sql-server> tag, and get better attention!

Comment: use table variable

Comment: You wouldn't need this if you weren't constructing dynamic SQL with a column name -- which *might* be the right thing to do, but just as often isn't. I recommend reading [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for a lengthy but thorough discussion on techniques to achieve this, a lot of which don't involve dynamic SQL, and even those that do don't involve completely arbitrary strings that are susceptible to injection (like this approach is).

Comment: For a single column, if you do have determined that dynamic SQL is the way to go, the simplest way to get the value is an output parameter: `DECLARE @i INT; EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @i = 3', N'@i INT OUTPUT', @i = @i OUTPUT; SELECT @i;`. The syntax for this is clumsy with seemingly redundant declarations and `OUTPUT`, but all components are actually necessary. Erland Sommarskog has [another write-up](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) with more details on how to do that in general between procedures (most of which is also appropriate to an ad-hoc batch).

Comment: You haven't explicitly stated that the query will ONLY ever return 1 row. If it returns more than one then what do you do with the value? If you go down the route of the answers suggested then you must also ensure only one value is returned for that pattern. If you expect more than one value then change the query to `INSERT INTO <output table> SELECT <column> etc` and then you can use the table in the next query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You use an output parameter:

```
declare @query Nvarchar(max);
declare @ColumnName Nvarchar(max);
declare @outval <type>;  -- whatever type

set @ColumnName = 'MyColumn'
set @query = 'Select @outval =' +  @ColumnName + ' from [MyTable] where [MyCondition]';

execut sp_executesql @query,
        N'@outval <type> output',
        @outval = @outval output;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, If the select query returns more than one record, does the query work?

Comment: @Atk - It depends what you mean by work. You will get one value out in the output variable. However as it is a variable it can only hold one value, so if the select query returns multiple values, you'll get the last one from the result set.

Comment: @Atk . . . This answers the question that the OP asked, and that question has this query in it.  If you or the OP have a question about returning multiple values, that should be asked as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

Store the results in table variable and then convert it into XML.

```
    Declare @xml XML
    declare @query Nvarchar(max)
    declare @ColumnName Nvarchar(max)
    set @ColumnName = 'MyColumn'
    declare @Table as TABLE(
    MyColumn varchar(Max)-- Your Column datatype
    )

    SET @query = 'Select ' +  @ColumnName + ' from [MyTable] WHERE [MyCondition]'

    INSERT INTO @Table
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query 

    select @xml=MyColumn from @Table for XML PATH('')
```

Answer (score 0):

How you want to pass returned result to other query?
What i can think of create a function return a table and call that function on other query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test (@id int)
RETURNS @testTable TABLE(id int)  
AS  
begin
insert into  @testTable select id from @your_table where id = @id
return
end
```

This will return a table you can check using :

```
select * from test(2); --will give you a table
```

If you want to use in a query:

```
`select * from @second_table where id in (select * from test2(@id parameter))` --- will filter query by id returned by function.
```